# What is reason of Warning "Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier"?

Tags: ios, objective-c-nullability

```
+ (UIColor*) getColorWithHexa(NSString*)hexString;
```

[image]:

This is a method definition in my class. It's causing a warning. What is cause of similar warnings and how can these be resolved?

I am returning an UIColor object, while that question relates to blocks, which is given in comments.

So, it's helpful.

Comment: Don't post microscopic screenshots. Post code! Copy & paste is pretty easy.

Comment: @vadian both Questions are totally different. This questions relates to What is reason, its not a solution, or anything mentioned in your link. Here its a method, while that is complete separate block.

Comment: e.g. `+ (UIColor * _Nullable) getColorWithHexa(NSString * _Nonnull)hexString;`, but you can fit your class's entire interface between the `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` directives as well, which defines `_Nonnull` for every object automatically.

Answer (score 16):

> **NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN/END:**
>
> Annotating any pointer in an Objective-C header file causes the
>   compiler to expect annotations for the entire file, bringing on a
>   cascade of warnings. Given that most annotations will be nonnull, a
>   new macro can help streamline the process of annotating existing
>   classes. Simply mark the beginning and end of a section of your header
>   with NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN and ..._END, then mark the exceptions.

So,you have simply do.

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
+ (UIColor*) getColorWithHexaCode:(NSString*)hexString;
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

This is defined in

> "NSObjCRuntime.h"
>
> #define NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN _Pragma("clang assume_nonnull begin")
>    #define NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END   _Pragma("clang assume_nonnull end")

Comment: NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN / END is really simple, until you specify a single non null parameter and then you'll be hounded by 'missing nullability type specifier' warnings for the rest of your life. Quite possibly beyond that.

Answer (score 9):

You got this warning when somewhere in the file you used either `_Nonnull`, `_Nullable`, `_Null_unspecified`, `__nullable`, `__nonnull`, `nullable` or `nonnull`. Could also happen if the specifier was added through a macro.

To fix the warning:

- you can remove all occurrences of nullability (not recommended)
- you can assume all parameters and returned values are `_Nonnull` using `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` (recommended)

Comment: As far as I can tell this description is correct, but do you have a source with more detail on the intended semantics? The Clang documentation at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wnullability-completeness describes the diagnostic text but not its actual meaning.

Comment: The only definitive reference I have so far is the Clang implementation itself: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/c9e46219f38da5c3fbfe41012173dc893516826e/clang/lib/Sema/SemaType.cpp#L4297-L4302